# CSS Changes after full load

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am running a WordPress site (v3.6.1) with the **Kaleido** theme.
I am using the WPGForm plugin to display google forms on the site.

I have added a form, and it is properly showing up. I am styling the form from the theme's main stylesheet. I took the classes and divs from the plugin stylesheet and moved it over to the primary theme css.

On load, the elements that I style show properly. That only happens for a second.
Essentially, the properly styled elements flash and then they default back to the some other styles.

Here is a link to the issue:
http://maefgives.org/apply/curriculum-grant-application/

Answer (score 0):

By default it takes the style from plugin class **.entry-content**. Try to override your style using **!important** with class name of div on your form.

Comment: I understand the purpose of !important and how to use it, but I don't understand what you mean by "with class name of div on your form".

Comment: I just mentioned to override your CSS style with default plugin css using class or id name you specified on your DOM design.